# How to write Cascading parameter using DAX in Report Builder

Tags: reporting-services, dax, ssrs-2012, reportbuilder3.0, powerbi-paginated-reports

I have a Power BI dataset as a data source in Power BI Report Builder.
I have use DAX expression to generate the parameter as shown below:

```
EVALUATE SUMMARIZECOLUMNS('DimensionList'[TopLevel], 'DimensionList'[SubLevel], 'DimensionList'[Dimension], RSCustomDaxFilter(@DimensionListTopLevel,EqualToCondition,[DimensionList].[TopLevel],String), RSCustomDaxFilter(@DimensionListSubLevel,EqualToCondition,[DimensionList].[SubLevel],String), RSCustomDaxFilter(@DimensionListDimension,EqualToCondition,[DimensionList].[Dimension],String))
```

However, this is not cascading parameter.
How can I rewrite this to cascade from TopLevel to SubLevel and finally Dimension?